# Google Play Store Auto-Updates across different release tracks

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, auto-update

Currently in the Google Play development console I have many users using an open testing track. I wish to fully publish an update of the app to the Play Store, and I am doing this by pushing a different closed testing track to production.

However, I wish to ensure that users using the existing open testing app will not be automatically updated to the production track, as they specifically need to stay on their current app version.

The mechanisms of Google Play updates are a little unclear. If users have 'Auto-Update' enabled on their Play Store settings, will they be updated from Open Testing to Production track if the production track is a newer version? Thanks.